# IBM Cloud: How to access DNS entries via API when setup under "Classic Infrastructure"

Tags: ibm-cloud

Our DNS zones were setup under Softlayer and are now accessable in IBM Cloud via "Classic Infrastructure".

I would like to be able to access these (get, update) via API.

1) Is [this api doc](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cis/dnsrecords#list-all-dns-records) the correct place to reference for "classic Infrastructure" ?

If so, then how would I locate the "crn" for my instance?  as per `/v1/{crn}/zones/{zone_identifier}/dns_records`

2) Or should I be using https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest/ ?

Comment: You can use both, but if you want to use https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest/, in the following link you will find some dns rest api examples such as get, update: https://sldn.softlayer.com/python/dns_management/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: ...but it is about increasing "programming knowledge" [source](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/) of an Application Programming Interface all within a specific tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the [Softlayer SLDN](http://%20https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/rest/) for the classic DNS instance. For DNS specifically you can use the following APIs

https://sldn.softlayer.com/tags/dns/